# Can Jeremiah 17:5 be validly interpreted as a prohibition against "Tradition"?

Tags: hermeneutical-approaches, law, jeremiah

> **NASB, Jeremiah 17:5** — Thus says the Lord, “Cursed is the man who trusts in mankind And makes flesh his strength, And whose heart turns away from the Lord.”

Can this passage be validly used to counter doctrines that tradition ***must*** be relied upon as an authority for properly interpreting Scripture?

***Does Jeremiah support this interpretation, or is it possibly mistranslated?***

I'm thinking specifically in reference to Rabbinic "Oral Law" and ["Catholic Dogmas", (Wikipedia Link)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dogma_in_the_Catholic_Church) that might assert theocratic authority which demands trust in their own, exclusive, preservation of some "divine tradition".

Comment: I don't see how the text, even in the translation provided, has anything to do with the question you're asking.

Comment: Speaking from a denomination which holds to such verses, I don't believe this passage would include any prohibition against the value of traditional interpretations. However, it might apply to people who trust decisions or teachings by other men, which are not supported by Scripture. For instance, in help understanding a verse, we might look back and read historical interpretations, but if, for instance, a pope said something of his own, without a clear appeal to Scripture, we would run from it. So, maybe consider rewording it to be distinct from "interpretation".

Comment: @elikakohen I was going to write an edit, but I feel like I was either adding too much or essentially trying to write an answer myself. Then, I noticed Gina gave an amazing answer that seems to cover those points, so maybe there's no need for an edit.

Comment: Alright - took another stab at clarifying/condensing the question.

Answer (score 2):

The immediate concern was Judah's dependence upon the alliance they had made with idolatrous Egypt to protect them from the Assyrians and Babylonians.  See Isa. 31:1-3.  They were forgetting to trust in God, who had fought for them and protected them during all the battles to overcome the wicked when they had moved into the lands of Canaan.

Clarke's Commentary on vs. 5,

> "Cursed be the man that trusteth in man - This reprehends their vain confidence in trusting in Egypt, which was too feeble itself to help, and, had it been otherwise, too ill disposed towards them to help them heartily. An arm of flesh is put here for a weak and ineffectual support. And he who, in reference to the salvation of his soul, trusts in an arm of flesh - in himself or others, or in any thing he has done or suffered, will inherit a curse instead of a blessing."  Source: [here](http://www.studylight.org/commentaries/acc/jeremiah-17.html)

Matthew Poole's Commentary:

> "It was the great sin of this people, for which they are often taxed in holy writ, 2 Chronicles 16:7 28:16,20 Isa 30:1,2 31:1,2, when any danger threatened them for their sins, to make leagues with and flee to foreign idolatrous nations to help and succour them, and to repose a confidence in them, and so bolster up themselves in their wicked and sinful courses, promising themselves deliverance from the dangers that threatened them by the power of their confederates and allies. This sin the prophet here reflecteth upon, that while their hearts
>
> departed from God, they would yet encourage themselves from the hoped-for help of men. The prophet from God declares that such are and shall be cursed, and mentioned man, under the notion of
>
> flesh, to show his frailty and impotency to help against, the mighty power and wrath of God; withal showing us that God alone is the true object of our faith and confidence, as well for the things of this life as those of another life, and that none
>
> whose heart departeth from God can with any security look for any help from the creature. "  Source: [here](http://biblehub.com/commentaries/jeremiah/17-5.htm)

YHWH was always using the weaker man (David vs. Goliath), or a seemingly impossible task (the walls of Jericho) to point out that it was God's will, and not man's strength which prevailed.

We are to rely upon Him, and put our full faith and dependence upon Him.  When we begin to rely upon our strength alone, as though we have control over everything around us, then we loose sight that He is our creator and everything that we have is because of Him.

Psa. 71:1-3,

> ": In Thee, O Jehovah, I have trusted, Let me not be ashamed to the age.
>
> 2 In Thy righteousness Thou dost deliver me, And dost cause me to escape, Incline unto me Thine ear, and save me.
>
> 3 Be to me for a rock -- a habitation, To go in continually, Thou hast given command to save me, For my rock and my bulwark [art] Thou."  (YLT)

Ultimately, God's word is not up for our private interpretation (1 Pet. 1:20). We are not allowed to make His word mean anything we want it to mean.  Only God interprets.

Dan. 2:28,

> " but there is a God in the heavens, a revealer of secrets, and He hath made known... "  (YLT)

God's word is the final authority on God's word.  The scriptures interpret the scriptures.  We must seek out the original meaning and use from within His word, and learn of Him.

Neh. 8:8,

> "and they read in the book, in the law of God, explaining -- so as to give the meaning, and they give understanding to the convocation."  (YLT)

Prov. 3:5,

> "Trust in the Lord with all thine heart; and lean not unto thine own understanding."  (KJV)

Matt. 13:36,

> "Then having let away the multitudes, Jesus came to the house, and his disciples came near to him, saying, `Explain to us the simile of the darnel of the field.'"  (YLT)

It is God who explains.  We must rely upon the scriptures, and not upon man's understanding. The Berean's were checking what Paul told them against what the scriptures said, and the Holy Spirit called them "more noble":

Acts 17:11,

> "These were **more noble** than those in Thessalonica, in that they received the word with all readiness of mind, and **searched the scriptures daily**, whether those things were so."  (KJV)

Comment: Gina - +1.  Thank you!  I just need a little bit to go through all of this.  And thank you again, this amazing.

Answer (score -3):

Psalm 119:105

> Your word is a lamp to my feet
>   And a light to my path.

We must be guided by the Word first and foremost.

We are also commanded to trust in the Lord

> Proverbs 3:5-6
>   Trust in the Lord with all your heart,
>   And lean not on your own understanding;
>   6 In all your ways acknowledge Him,
>   And He shall direct[a] your paths.

We must not forget that Chris the Living Word and The Written Word (bible) and inseperable. today many people forget this.

> In the beginning was the Word, and the Word was with God, and the Word was God.

Finally, to answer your question, we look at the original "Official Theocratic tradtionalists" the Pharisees.

> Mark 7:8-9
>     8- For laying aside the commandment of God, you hold the tradition of men[c] —the washing of pitchers and cups, and many other such things you do.”
>   9-He said to them, “All too well you reject the commandment of God, that you may keep your tradition.

Following exclusively any tradition or dogma, simply because of of the percieved authority behind it, means that you have put your TRUST and even FAITH in that entity, the Catholic Church etc.

This is a Misplacing of our Faith/Trust like in your original verse from Jeremiah.
Our Faith/Trust is purely in the Word of God, Living Word (Christ) and revealed in the Written Word (bible), as long as teaching lines up with the Word, we can accept it. But we don't accept it because of who teaches it, we accept it BECAUSE it lines up with the Word.

EDIT-- In response to the feedback i recieved. I think you ARE getting a correct understanding of this verse, and i was just providing more biblical support for your argument. showing that Yes this is a good thing to pull from your verse in Jeremiah, it is definitely a strong biblical theme also to be found elucidated elsewhere.

Comment: But does Jeremiah support this conclusion or is it mistranslate?

Comment: Welcome to Hermeneutics; we're glad to have you here. If you have not yet, please take the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to see what makes us different from other sites, and what goes into making a strong answer.

Comment: I've downvoted this, because even though I don't presently understand the question being asked, the question does have a specific text indicated for discussion: Jeremiah 17.5. Your response only briefly mentions Jeremiah, instead leaping from Psalms to Proverbs to Mark. Answers need to directly address the text being asked about.

Comment: I added an edit to try and address this feedback from these comments